# Magento2 : add New address type to customer

Tags: magento2.2, sales-order, quote, customer-address

I want to Create a new address type "`neighbors address / alternate address` " . To assign it to customer i have created new customer attribute ( just like "`default_shipping`" and "`default_billing`" ) "`alternate_address`" and saved `address_id` against it . But how to integrate it with Quote and order . They only save a string "shipping or billing"  in `address_type` column . Where i would like to have it as alternate

Comment: Hello did you find any workaround to create an extra address set because I also want to do the same thing! Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153344)

Comment: I know that this is now a question but I don't really have the reputation needed.

Comment: @dandrits Check answer .

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar  I created new address type using installer script. Now how can I add it in frontend and save in table ?

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar  can you  please share code how to add new address type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue i created a plugin

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Validator">
    <plugin  name="Mycompany_Sales_after_validator" sortOrder="10" type="MyCompany\Sales\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Validator"/>
</type>
```

And in plugin class

```
namespace MyCompany\Sales\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Validator as parentValidator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress;

/**
 * Class Validator
 * @package MyCompany\Sales\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address
 */
class Validator
{
    const REGISTRED_ADDRESS = 'alternate';
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $required = [
        'parent_id' => 'Parent Order Id',
        'postcode' => 'Zip code',
        'lastname' => 'Last name',
        'street' => 'Street',
        'city' => 'City',
        'email' => 'Email',
        'country_id' => 'Country',
        'firstname' => 'First Name',
        'address_type' => 'Address Type',
    ];


    /**
     * @param Address\Validator $subject subject
     * @param callable          $proceed Closure
     * @param Address           $address Address
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
     */
    public function aroundValidate(
        parentValidator $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        Address $address
    ) {
        $warnings = [];
        foreach ($this->required as $code => $label) {
            if (!$address->hasData($code)) {
                $warnings[] = sprintf('%s is a required field', $label);
            }
        }

        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($address->getEmail(), EmailAddress::class)) {
            $warnings[] = 'Email has a wrong format';
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Please enter a valid email address.'));
        }
        if (!in_array($address->getAddressType(), [
                                                   Address::TYPE_BILLING,
                                                   Address::TYPE_SHIPPING,
                                                   self::REGISTRED_ADDRESS,
            ])) {
            $warnings[] = 'Address type doesn\'t match required options';
        }

        return $warnings;
    }//end aroundValidate()


}//end class
```

This is old implementation(In after plugin there were no input parameter) and might not be best implementation. Try if you can avoid around plugin and also call proceed .

Comment: I created new address type using installer script. Now how can I add it in frontend and save in table ?

Comment: Yes just save the address id against the attribute value for customer

Comment: Can you tell me in which table I need to save address id and from where I can find address id ?

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar can you please share your full source code here if you can.

Comment: @Kishan Patadia  can you please share code how to add new address type using installer script.