# Magento 2: Create new customer address type

Tags: customer-address, magento2.3.2

How can we create new customer address type(like billing and shipping) in Magento 2.3.x ? That new address type should work same like billing or shipping i.e. it should be assigned to particular order, customer etc...

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227100/magento2-add-new-address-type-to-customer?rq=1